# Factorization for P(A, B, C, D) that includes P(A, B | C, D) and its visualization

Tags: graphical-model

I was revisiting some basic concepts on graphical models and factorization of distributions and noticed that all the examples I see only have factors that include, at most, one conditioned random variable (i.e. P(A | B, C, D)). Is there are reason that I shouldn't (or can't) decompose P(A, B, C, D) to include a factor like P(A, B | C, D)? If I can't/shouldn't, why? If I can, how should the visualization look like? Should it look like this?

[image: factorization of P(A, B, C, D) that includes P(A, B | C, D)]

If yes, isn't this the same visualization for a decomposition like the following: P(A, B, C, D) = P(A | C, D) * P(B | C, D) * P(C) * P(D)? If yes, does that mean two different factorizations can have the same visualization?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That could make sense if $A$ and $B$ depend on each other, but if they do not then it may introduce unnecessary complication for the graphical model.  See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_model#Cyclic_Directed_Graphical_Models

Comment: Thanks for the response, Henry.

Does that mean that the visualization I post would be only applicable to P(A, B, C, D) = P(A | C, D) * P(B | C, D) * P(C) * P(D) but not to P(A, B, C, D) = P(A, B | C, D) * P(C) * P(D) ?

Comment: Moving away from graphical models, if $A$ and $B$ are conditionally independent given $C$ and $D$ then this mean $P(A,B \mid C,D) = P(A \mid C,D) \,  P(B \mid C,D)$.  But in graphical models your visualisation would suggest using the right hand side [and multiplying it by $P(C)P(D)$ where $C$ and $D$ are presumed to be unconditionally independent of each other]